# how to keep track of Lean Tween function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leantween

I want to know the time left to complete the animation as I am using unity asset Lean Tween to scale down my time bar, so when 5 seconds are left till the time run out I want to play sound of closing time.
I was able to know when the animation is gonna end
`LeanTween.scaleX(timebar.gameObject, 1f, time).setOnComplete(this.Gameover)`
but how i can a get time left to complete? I have looked through documentation but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad didn't you read the question? Both in header and description of question, OP states, question related to **LeanTween** library not Unity animation. LeanTween library, modify components of object directly, don't create animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every LeanTween function returns an instance of **[LtDescr](http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LTDescr.html)** class. This class has access to variable of animation and methods that can control it. You can get total time by **time** and passed time by **passed**. Remained time equal to **time-passed**.

```
LtDescr animation = LeanTween.scaleX(timebar.gameObject, 1f, time).setOnComplete(this.Gameover);
var remainedTime = animation.time - animation.passed;
```

Comment: i know about this, but the time field only gives me the total time not the time left like is there any way i can get some vale while the leantween animation is running?

Comment: @UmerAsghar sorry for misinfo. Try to use **time-passed** instead of **time**. I also updated the answer.